Creating a local proxy server in python
I have two computers computer 1 and computer 2 on the same network. I'm trying to make computer 1 act as a proxy server so when I send a request from computer 2 using its ip address as a proxy, the request will pass through computer 1.
After trying multiple approaches, this is my code on the client side:
import requests

# Proxy server settings
PROXY_HOST = '192.168.1.112'
PROXY_PORT = 8888
url = 'https://www.google.com'
proxies = {
    'http': f'http://{PROXY_HOST}:{PROXY_PORT}',
    'https': f'http://{PROXY_HOST}:{PROXY_PORT}'
}

try:
    response = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
    print("Response from server:")
    print(response.content.decode('utf-8')) 
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")

And this is the code on my server side (computer 1):
import socket
import threading
import ssl

LOCAL_HOST = '0.0.0.0'
PROXY_PORT = 8888

def handle_client(client_socket):
    request = client_socket.recv(4096)
    print(f"Received request from client: {request}")

    first_line = request.split(b'\n')[0]
    method = first_line.split()[0]

    if method == b'CONNECT':
        handle_https(client_socket, request)
    else:
        handle_http(client_socket, request)

def handle_https(client_socket, request):
    # Extract the host and port from the CONNECT request
    first_line = request.split(b'\n')[0]
    host, port = first_line.split()[1].split(b':')
    port = int(port)

    remote_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    remote_socket.connect((host.decode('utf-8'), port))

    client_socket.send(b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n')

    context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
    client_ssl = context.wrap_socket(client_socket, server_side=True)
    remote_ssl = context.wrap_socket(remote_socket, server_hostname=host.decode('utf-8'))


    forward_data(client_ssl, remote_ssl)

def handle_http(client_socket, request):
    remote_host = 'www.example.com'
    remote_port = 80

    remote_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    remote_socket.connect((remote_host, remote_port))
    remote_socket.send(request)

    remote_response = remote_socket.recv(4096)
    print(f"Received response from remote server: {remote_response}")

    client_socket.send(remote_response)

    remote_socket.close()
    client_socket.close()

def forward_data(sock1, sock2):
    sockets = [sock1, sock2]
    while True:
        for sock in sockets.copy():
            try:
                data = sock.recv(4096)
                if data:
                    other_sock = sock2 if sock == sock1 else sock1
                    other_sock.sendall(data)
                else:
                    sock.close()
                    sockets.remove(sock)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error: {e}")
                sock.close()
                sockets.remove(sock)

def start_proxy_server():
    proxy_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    proxy_socket.bind((LOCAL_HOST, PROXY_PORT))
    proxy_socket.listen(5)
    print(f"Proxy server listening on port {PROXY_PORT}...")

    while True:
        client_socket, addr = proxy_socket.accept()
        print(f"Accepted connection from {addr[0]}:{addr[1]}")

        # Handle client request in a separate thread
        client_handler = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client_socket,))
        client_handler.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_proxy_server()

If I send an http request that works well, but when sending an https request I'm getting this error on the server side during the handshake process:

ssl.SSLError: [SSL: NO_SHARED_CIPHER] no shared cipher (_ssl.c:1000)

I tried to add this to my code but it didn't help:
cipher = 'DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256'
context.set_ciphers(cipher)


The error you get is because the proxy does not provide a certificate. If the client only accepts ciphers which requires certificate based authentication but the server has no certificates, then there are no common cipher - hence no shared ciphers.
How to solve the problem depends on what you want to do in the first place: if you just want to pass through the original HTTPS traffic, then you should not use any SSL in your proxy at all. Just pass the data in both directions after you've send the answer to the CONNECT request.
If you instead want to do SSL interception, i.e. man-in-the-middle the HTTPS traffic in your proxy, then you need to configure a certificate on your client_socket which matches the hostname in the requested URL, like the original server certificate does. If you want to have an universal proxy for arbitrary domains then you would need to create this certificate on the fly for the respective target domain. And of course the client must trust the certificate, usually by trusting a constant issuer CA for a dynamically generated (target specific) certificate.

Thanks for the useful information. I actually don't have much experience in sockets and ssl, I just wanted to pass through the original https traffic in the most simple way.
That's because on my client side there's a software that blocks me from sending requests to certain websites, I tried to change the DNS but that didn't help, now I just want to send that request as if it was sent from the other computer

What should I do in that case?

@user2401856: like I said: if you just want to forward the traffic simply pass it in both directions. You cannot assume a specific order of traffic here, so use a select-loop or threading to make sure that both directions are handled in parallel
